# Drawing a line between a logo and text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 and I need to draw a thin line after the logo.png below. There should be no spaces between the line and logo
and still no spaces between the text and line.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  d-flex py-4">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="index" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
      </a>
      <h2 class="my-auto font-size-medium">Zombie Testing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
<nav>
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: side-note: you have a typo in your nav closing tag.

Comment: A line like a border line?

Comment: A line like <hr/> and there should be no spaces below the image and no spaces above the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin: 0` to get rid of the space between the elements

```css
h2, hr {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  d-flex py-4">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="index" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
      </a>
      <hr>
      <h2 class="my-auto font-size-medium">Zombie Testing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add a `border-top` to the text by adding the `border-top`-class

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  d-flex py-4">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="index" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
      </a>
      <h2 class="my-auto font-size-medium border-top">Zombie Testing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, was just thinking the same thing. Or even `border-bottom` on the Div which contains the image.

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm  d-flex py-4">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
      <a href="index" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="images/logo.png" style="padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;marin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;" />
      </a>
      <hr style="padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;margin:0px;">
      <h2  style="padding-top:0px ;padding-bottom:0px ;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;">Zombie Testing</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
<nav>
```

check at this:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/t6p4dubo/12/

Comment: There should be no space at the bottom of the image. The image should seat on the line and there should be no space on top of the text. Yours shows a lot of spaces

Comment: @Baba now its showing correct I have edited it..